# WPF with Prism and DryIOC fails when dependency injecting IOption<> settings in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: wpf, .net-core, configuration, prism

I'm migrating a WPF based on Prism and DryIOC to .Net Core 3.1. I'm finding that DryIOC fails to handle dependency resolution when it comes to the .net core configuration features. I've tried injecting IOption<>, IConfiguration, etc, nothing using the .Net Core Configuration will resolve without throwing an exception.

I thought that it may be that DryIOC wasn't fully compatible yet with the Microsoft DI, but I've produced a number of sandbox attempts that show that DryIOC does work with web projects using .Net Core. I've also proven that I can get WPF projects to work when not using Prism and DryIOC. I have a sample app that shows the problem I'm getting.

The sample resolves a class object and tries to resolve a configuration section from the file appsettings.json into the MainWindowViewModel. My class object resolves just fine, but blows up when trying to resolve IOptions using this code

```
public MainWindowViewModel(
    IUser user
    // Comment out the next line to avoid the DI exception
    , IOptions<AppSettings> settings
)
{
    _user = user;

    // Comment out the next line to avoid the DI exception
    _settings = settings;
}
```

The setup code for the ConfigurationBuilder is as follows:

```
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile(
            $"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json",
            optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    public IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new DryIocServiceProviderFactory(container: Container.GetContainer()))
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                // <-- Here is where I'm using IOptions<AppSettings> dependency object -->
                services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppSettings)));
            })
            .ConfigureContainer<Container>((hostContext, container) =>
            {
                // <-- the debugger shows right here, the IOptions<> stuff is in the container -->
                var stuff = container.GetServiceRegistrations();
            });

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            ;

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        CreateHostBuilder(args: new string[] { }).Build();
```

Please refer to the sample project for the entire setup.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvdDo8v2RmDrjDeBRHfhkHH_kXbK?e=37GHDF

I get the following exception

Unable to resolve WpfPrismCore.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel IsResolutionCall
  from Container without Scope
 with Rules with {AutoConcreteTypeResolution}
 with Made={FactoryMethod=ConstructorWithResolvableArguments}
Where no service registrations found
  and no dynamic registrations found in 0 of Rules.DynamicServiceProviders
  and nothing found in 1 of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers

at DryIoc.Throw.It(Int32 error, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) in D:\Dev\DryIoc\src\DryIoc\Container.cs:line 10684
   at DryIoc.Container.TryThrowUnableToResolve(Request request) in D:\Dev\DryIoc\src\DryIoc\Container.cs:line 939
   at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IContainer.ResolveFactory(Request request) in D:\Dev\DryIoc\src\DryIoc\Container.cs:line 918
   at DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCacheFactoryDelegate(Type serviceType, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) in D:\Dev\DryIoc\src\DryIoc\Container.cs:line 256
   at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve(Type serviceType, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) in D:\Dev\DryIoc\src\DryIoc\Container.cs:line 230
   at DryIoc.Resolver.Resolve(IResolver resolver, Type serviceType) in D:\Dev\DryIoc\src\DryIoc\Container.cs:line 5884
   at Prism.DryIoc.Ioc.DryIocContainerExtension.Resolve(Type type)
   at Prism.PrismApplicationBase.b__6_0(Object view, Type type)
   at Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocationProvider.AutoWireViewModelChanged(Object view, Action`2 setDataContextCallback)
   at Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)

Answer (score 0):

try add in ConfigureServices first line.

```
services.TryAddSingleton(typeof(IOptionsSnapshot<>),typeof(OptionsManager<>));
```